# 16" MacBook Pro blue pixel aliasing on external display

Tags: mac, display, macbook-pro, external-display, anti-aliasing

I have a new MBP 2019 16" with the AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB vid card.

When I plugged my [LG UltraFine 5K](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMUB2LL/A/lg-ultrafine-5k-display) display in via USB-C I noticed strange light blue aliasing around font and images.

Example (bad):

[image]

Here is the same text (in same window) but on the MBP built-in retina display:
[image]

It doesn't show up great here, but its very obvious to the naked eye.

It happens on everything (not just font):
[image]

What is strange is I do NOT see this issue if I change the display resolution scale to `2560x1440` or below in Display Settings:

[image]

I know it is NOT a problem with the external monitor, because when I plug it into my late 2018 15" MBP I do not see the problem.

I have a second 4K LG monitor plugged in at the same time, and it is not exhibiting this issue (no matter what resolution scale is selected).

I've tried:

- Disabling font smoothing
- Restarting
- Changing monitor color profiles
- Using f.lux
- Only plugging in the UltraFine 5k

Any ideas what this is called or how I might fix? This is SUPER annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current workaround is to disable True Tone in the Displace preference panel.

Not ideal obviously. Hoping someone from Apple picks up on my discussion [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250963040)

Comment: I'm experiencing this too in the LG UltraFine 5K display, and there's no way to disable Truetone in clamshell mode. But even when I do open up my laptop to disable True Tone, that doesn't have any bearing on the aliasing going on in the external display. Still persists.